# how to change class value javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello i was just wondering would there be a way to change the class value of `("list_element")[0];` every time if has done `("close")[0].click();` i would like it to go up by one each time it has done `("close")[0].click();` how could i do this?

```js
var refreshIntervalId;
window.addEventListener("onkeydown", keyDown, true);
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown);

function keyDown() {
  var e = window.event;
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 188:
      start();
      break;
    case 190:
      stopA();
      break;
  }
}

function start() {
  stop();
  refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {

    function sleep(ms) {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    async function demo() {
      document.getElementsByClassName("list_element")[2].click();
      await sleep(1000);
      document.getElementsByClassName("aclist")[1].click();
      await sleep(1000);
      document.getElementById("pro").click();
      await sleep(1000);
      document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0].click();
    }

    demo();
  }, 5000);
}

function stop() {
  if (refreshIntervalId != null) {
    clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
    refreshIntervalId = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "class value". BTW, you haven't added any HTML.

Comment: Please fix your snippet into a [mcve]